Can I using import without annotating the script to be type='module'
Actually, I am using a non-module javascript files
I have installed creditor and I want to use Base64UploadAdapter from ckeditor
the official documentation tells me to use
import Base64UploadAdapter from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload";
i

inside my js, but when I use this, it will say that

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'Base64UploadAdapter'. import call expects one or two arguments.

When I change the script to
<script src='test.js' type='module'>

I have to set some functions from test.js to export function
For example:
export function test() {
   alert('this is testing');
}

But I have used directly test() from other many many js files already.  If I change to export I have to add
import { test } from 'test.js'

before using test function.
I wonder how can I fix this problem? Thanks!
I have tried following the instruction from official ckeditor5
